# solr ranking using an existent field

Tags: solr

I'm loading into Solr data from a mysql database with DataImportHandler. Every document contains a `popularity` field (`int` type) that is calculated from another application and saved into mysql (this field is based on some rules relatives to the domain of application).

How can i use this value to improve solr ranking? Would be correct to **sum** the solr `score` with `popularity` value?
How [bf](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebf_BoostFunctions_Parameter) can be used here?

Comment: To be fair, it’s hard to give you the right answer without business case. I could imagine several of them and it would differ how to use this popularity. One could be to sort on both fields, or do a multiplication or just apply boost by popularity. What I could say for sure - summing is a bad idea 100%

Comment: Also the score values doesn't make any sense except for a specific query, so summing it (additive) will not give the same weight to the popularity field across queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point that'd probably work is multiplying the score by a sublinear function that increases (slowly) with popularity. For example,

```
newScore = score * log(1 + 0.5 * popularity)
```

To apply this boost you should use Solr's [EDisMax query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) and pass [the boost parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) with the following value:

```
&boost=log(sum(1, product(0.5, popularity)))
```

where popularity is the name of the field. You don't need to use the `bf` parameter since you should use a multiplicative boost, not an additive one.

The reason for adding 1 is to handle the case in which `popularity=0` (so if each document's popularity is always at least 1, you don't need to add 1). The strength of the popularity effect can be increased or decreased by changing the 0.5 factor to some other value. For example, you can use a factor of 2 to increase the effect:

```
newScore = score * log(1 + 2 * popularity)
```

A good factor is probably around `9 / m` where `m` is what you expect should be the median popularity, since in this case the boost of a "median document" (median in the sense that its popularity equals `m`) is going to be 1 (that is, its score won't be boosted at all).

Again, this is just a starting point and you'll have to try out different boosting functions until you find one that performs well.

Comment: thanks, this is a good start to me. given this approach `newScore = score * log(1 + popularity)`, how can be espressed using `bf`? (i'm missing how to get the original "score")

Comment: @GeorgeLivanoss, I've edited my answer. See if it helps now.